# How many connections a Python Django App opens by default?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a couple of services which query objects from the database.

```
Event.objects.filter
Connection.objects.filter
```

and other methods to retrieve different objects from MySQL database.
I come from JVM background, and I know that to setup a JDBC connection, you need a connector. A programmer can open a connection, query the database and close the connection. A programmer also can use Hibernate, which handles connection according to the configuration. Also it is possible to use pooled connections, so connections are not closed and removed, but stored in the pool untill they are needed.

However, I checked my teams Python Django code, and I did not find how db connection is configured. The only thing I got is which does not configure connections.

```
# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases
try:
    import database_password
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'NAME': "mydb",
            'USER': 'user',
            'PASSWORD': database_password.password,
            'HOST': '10.138.67.149',
            'PORT': '3306'
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is covered [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/databases/#general-notes). Each thread maintains its own connection.

Comment: @Alasdair It can be an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each thread maintains its own connection. See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/databases/#general-notes) for full details.

PostgreSQL + PgBouncer (connection pooler) + Django is a common setup. I'm not sure whether there's a similar connection pooler you could use with MySQL.